# Replace every other character

Tags: ruby, regex

how could i skip or replace every other character (could be anything) with regex?

```
"abc123.-def45".gsub(/.(.)?/, '@')
```

to get

```
"a@c@2@.@d@f@5"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the first character instead, and write it back:

```
"abc123.-def45".gsub(/(.)./, '\1@')
```

It's important that you don't make the second character optional. Otherwise, in an odd-length string, the last character would lead to a match, and a `@` would be appended. Without the `?`, the last character will simply fail and remain untouched.

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/KUfeV5)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to avoid replacing @ in sequences

```
"abc123.-def45".gsub(/([^@])[^@]/, '\1@')
```

Comment: That will offset the alternation by one (so that odd instead of even positions are replaced) if there's a single `@` though. E.g. `abcd@efgh` would lead to `a@c@@e@g@` instead of `a@c@@@f@h`.

Comment: thanks to you both for showing different methods of using regex

Answer (score 1):

The below code will also work:

```
irb(main):005:0> "abc123.-def45".chars.each_with_index.map {|e,i| !i.even? ? e = "@" : e}.join
=> "a@c@2@.@d@f@5"
```